# another meaning of 'light out'

Tags: meaning

> A: How long did this go on?
>
> B: It was starting to get ***light out***.

Does 'light out' mean 'Sun comes out'?
Or 'Sun goes down'?

(My native langue it not English. Please be kind to me. :-))

Comment: Hello, Lily. Please consider posting on [English Language Learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com/). Your questions are very basic for this site.

Comment: @Lily I also notice you have never "accepted" any answer. That's how we say "thank you" here (if an answer was good).

Comment: @WeatherVane Oh, I didn't know there is 'Accepting answer'. Thank you for noticing me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

B's sentence means

> It was starting to get light out**side**.

In other words, the event went on almost until dawn.

Comment: Thank you! It helped a lot!